# How to exclude a column out of multiple in select query in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have 3 tables out of which one is containing two foreign keys for the primary keys of the corresponding tables. Now I want to run a query which will fetch data from these tables and will store the result-set in a new table with only one primary key of each.

- Tab 1: CUSTOMER (cust_id, col2, col3.....)
- Tab 2: PRODUCT (prod-id, col2, col3.....)
- Tab 3: SALES (s_id, cust_id,prod_id, col2, col3.....)

Now, I want result-set to be stored in a new table "RES" containing one 'cust_id', one 'prod_id' along with rest columns rather than those of two columns.

Please help.........

Thank you :)

I tried like this:

```
select * 
into RES 
from customer c 
inner join sales s on s.cust_id = c.cust_id 
where c.cust_id in (select cust_id 
                    from sales 
                    group by cust_id 
                    having count(cust_id) >= 2) 
order by s.cust_id;
```

but I get this error:

> Msg 2705, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
>   Column names in each table must be unique. Column name 'cust_id' in table 'RES' is specified more than once.

Answer (score 0):

> Msg 2705, Level 16, State 3, Line 1 Column names in each table must be
>   unique. Column name 'cust_id' in table 'RES' is specified more than
>   once.

You are getting this error because you are inserting all the columns of tables `customer` and `sales` into `RES`, where `custid` column is present in both the tables.

Using `*` for insert is not a good practice. Instead of this you can change your query like following.

```
INSERT INTO RES(COL1,COL2.....COLN)
SELECT COL1, COL2, ........
FROM 
<QUERY>
```

Even you are using `SELECT .. INTO`, in this case also you select explicit columns.